# How to get the collapse to open depending if there is an error - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Hi all I have following [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5c854q?file=demo.js).

I have two inputs and that two inputs are mandatory.

First input name is `Name` and when I am submit with any values it says `Please input Name!` . This part was working great.

Second input, which name is `Short Info` was located in collapse. And that collapse is `<Form.Item>`, it's mean that user can press `+` and add multiple `Short Info` inputs.

My problem is with that `Short Info`. When user press submit only first input shows error. For `Short Info` user should open that collapse to see error, which is not good.

Now how can I automatically open that collapse panel if there is error ?

Here is my code.

```
    const [dataFromBackend, setDataFromBackend] = useState([]);

    const addNewField = () => {
     setDataFromBackend([...dataFromBackend]);
    };

    const submitForm = (values) => {
     console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
    };

    const Header = ({ remove, index }) => {
     return (
      <Col align="center" span={1} justify="end">
        <MinusCircleFilled
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            remove(index);
          }}
        />
      </Col>
     );
    };


     return (
      <>
      <Form
        name="validate_other"
        onFinish={submitForm}
        initialValues={{ values: [''] }}
      >
        <Form.Item
          name="name"
          label="Name"
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please input Name!',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.List name="values">
          {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
            return (
              <Row gutter={24}>
                <Col span={24} md={24}>
                  <Card
                    title="Price"
                    extra={
                      <PlusCircleFilled
                        style={{
                          cursor: 'pointer',
                          fontSize: '20px',
                          color: '#00AEE6',
                        }}
                        onClick={() => {
                          add();
                          addNewField();
                        }}
                      />
                    }
                  >
                    <div key={fields.key}>
                      {fields.map((field, i) => (
                        <div key={i}>
                          <Collapse accordion={true}>
                            <Panel
                              key={i}
                              header={<Header remove={remove} index={i} />}
                            >
                              <Col span={24} md={24}>
                                <Form.Item
                                  name={[field.name, 'shortinfo']}
                                  fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'shortinfo']}
                                  label={'Short Info'}
                                  rules={[
                                    {
                                      required: true,
                                      message: 'Please input short info!',
                                    },
                                  ]}
                                >
                                  <Input />
                                </Form.Item>
                              </Col>
                            </Panel>
                          </Collapse>
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            );
          }}
        </Form.List>
        <Button htmlType="submit">Save</Button>
      </Form>
      </>
    )
```

Please help me to resolve this problem, thanks.

Comment: is your `field.name` different for all fields?

Comment: No, it same for all, only `field.fieldKey` is different.

Comment: You could add a listener to the `onFinishFailed` of the form and check the paths for the SubInfo fields, dependend on if they are equal or not, set the collapse value

Comment: @sschwei1 , can you show it via code please?

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be as follows:

1. First of all, render all `<Panels>` inside the same `<Colapse>`, also remove `accordion={true}` from `Colapse` (so multiple Fields can be open at once) and add `forceRender={true}` to `Panels`, otherwise items inside a `Panel` are lazy loaded (if lazy load would be active, `<Form.Item>` wouldn't be rendered and don't show up as error)

```
<Collapse>
  {fields.map((field, i) => {
    return (
      <Panel
        ...
        forceRender={true}
        ...
      >
        ...
      </Panel>
    );
  })}
</Colapse>
```

---

2. Add a state to keep track of currently active keys and add it to the colapse, also remove the `<div key={i}>` it is not needed, since `<Panel key={i}>` is already a container, furthermore it will prevent `onChange` of `Colapse` to trigger and mess up your styling

```
const [activeKeysColapse, setactiveKeysColapse] = useState([]);

...

<Collapse
  activeKey={activeKeysColapse}
  onChange={(newActiveKeys) => {
    // otherwise panels couldn't be open/closed by click
    setactiveKeysColapse(newActiveKeys);
  }}
>
  {fields.map((field, i) => {
    return (
      <Panel
        key={i}
        forceRender={true}
      >
        ...
      </Panel>
    );
  })}
</Colapse>
```

---

3. Add `onFinishFailed` listener to form

```
const submitFormFailed = (errors) => {
  // get all errorFields from the list and map the
  // `activeKeys` to the index (because `<Panel key={i}>`)
  const newShortInfoErrors = errors.errorFields
    .filter((el) => el.name[0] === 'values')
    .map((el) => el.name[1].toString());

  // setting the state will close all fields which
  // are valid and open all with an error message
  setactiveKeysColapse(newShortInfoErrors);
};

...

<Form
  ...
  onFinishFail={submitFormFailed}
>
```

---

Based on the code on your StackBlitz, this will do exactly what you want

I hope this will solve your problem, if there is anything unclear, feel free to comment